# How to get id new record in yii createCommand?

Tags: php, yii

How to get id new record in yii createCommand?
i try this

```
$insert = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO {$tableName}(the_geom) values(ST_GeomFromText('{$cordinate}'));")->query();
```

and i add code

```
$insert_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID($insert);
```

the result is an error, please help me..

Comment: show the error you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sure you get the last id

If using postgresql

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID('table_sequence');
```

If using mysql

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

since `getLastInsertID` is accessor method you also call like this too

```
$lastID = Yii::app()->db->lastInsertID
```

May be this discussion helpful to you. please [click me!!](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19153-last-inserted-id/)

for official documention [click me!!](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#getLastInsertID-detail)

And In this thread there is a clear explanation of issue occurring during usage of getter/accessor and setter/mutator method as property in conditional check [click me!!](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#c1909)